# Showing data as a column name

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have three tables. I called them as Table A,Table B,Table C. 
And I have desired view which I want to get.

```
Table A
Aid         RegNum  BID         Value
2CE7D0A7    2000000 D5981DFC    OFFCRO
9D3C13AA    2000000 C58566C5    YCH - from 
9DDB90C4    2000000 812E9E75    Y
```

Table B is connected to Table A by Table B's foreign key in Table A

```
Table B

BID             Label                               ColumnName              Order
D5981DFC        Offered/Change Role                 StatusChangeCode        0
C58566C5        Offered/Role Change Comments        StatusChangeComments    1
812E9E75        Assessed                            StatusChangeAssessed    2
```

Table C has foreign key in Table A as well. Reg Num. Reg num is primary key in Table C

```
Table C 

Name        Surname     RegNum
Etibar      Hasanov     2000000
```

As you see there are column's names which are datas in Table B

```
DesiredView
Name        Surname     RegNum      StatusChangeCode    StatusChangeComments    StatusChangeAssessed
Etibar      Hasanov     2000000     OFFCRO              YCH - from              Y
```

Comment: show th equery you tried. use `pivot`

Comment: I know there will be pivoting.  but I don't know any idea how to show data as column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first selected columns names. In this table it brings **[StatusChangeAssessed],[StatusChangeCode],[StatusChangeComments]** . Then in the next query I setted @col ( column names ).

```
declare @nregnumber  nvarchar(10)='2000000';



   DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @runningquery  as nvarchar(max);       
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(rn) 
                    from
                    (
                      select columnname rn from tableb where exists ( select * from tablea where tablea.bid=tableb.bid and regnum=@nregnumber) 
                    ) t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');


set @runningquery='

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
      Name, SurName, C.RegNum, Value, B.ColumnName 
     FROM TableC C
     JOIN TableA A ON C.RegNum = A.RegNum
     JOIN TableB B on B.BID = A.BID
) AS Source
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Value)
    FOR [ColumnName] 
    in ( '+@cols+')
)AS Pvot'
exec (@runningquery)
```

Special thanks to Selva.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `PIVOT` table. Try something like this,

```
Create Table TableA(Aid varchar(50), RegNum int, BID Varchar(20), Value varchar(50))
insert into TableA values
('2CE7D0A7', 2000000, 'D5981DFC', 'OFFCRO'),
('9D3C13AA', 2000000, 'C58566C5', 'YCH - from' ),
('9DDB90C4', 2000000, '812E9E75', 'Y')


create Table TableB(BID Varchar(20), Label Varchar(50), ColumnName
 Varchar(50), [Order] int)

insert into TableB values
('D5981DFC', 'Offered/Change Role', 'StatusChangeCode', 0),
('C58566C5', 'Offered/Role Change Comments', 'StatusChangeComments', 1),
('812E9E75', 'Assessed', 'StatusChangeAssessed',  2)

Create Table TableC (Name Varchar(20), Surname  Varchar(20), RegNum int)
insert into TableC values
('Etibar', 'Hasanov', 2000000)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
      Name, SurName, C.RegNum, Value, B.ColumnName 
     FROM TableC C
     JOIN TableA A ON C.RegNum = A.RegNum
     JOIN TableB B on B.BID = A.BID
) AS Source
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Value)
    FOR [ColumnName] 
    in ( [StatusChangeCode], [StatusChangeComments],  [StatusChangeAssessed] )
)AS Pvot
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b16d/1/0)

If you are using `SQL server 2005`, according to [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx),

> When PIVOT and UNPIVOT are used against databases that are upgraded to
>   SQL Server 2005 or later, the compatibility level of the database must
>   be set to 90 or higher.

Comment: Selva, since we don't know column names , I used the last part of your answer and fixed it as I needed. I will publish the answer and will vote up your answer. Thanks.